# Android GraphView multiple series show/hide particular linegraph on touch

Tags: android, android-graphview

I am using [GraphView](http://www.android-graphview.org/mix-up-chart-types/) for Android with multiple series to show 2 graphs.
Is it even a possibility to show/hide one of the graphs on touch, because I couldn't find any documentation on the website?

Here is the source code:

```
graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[] {
    new DataPoint(0, 1),
    new DataPoint(1, 5),
    new DataPoint(2, 3),
    new DataPoint(3, 2),
    new DataPoint(4, 6)
});
graph.addSeries(series);

LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series2 = new LineGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[] {
    new DataPoint(0, 3),
    new DataPoint(1, 3),
    new DataPoint(2, 6),
    new DataPoint(3, 2),
    new DataPoint(4, 5)
});
graph.addSeries(series2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the way, if anyone stumbled upon this problem.
Created custom toggle/button that uses: `graph.removeSeries()/graph.addSeries()` and that should do the trick